# x2go keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, x2go

I installed x2go in an Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-29-generic x86_64) machine which I use as a server. On the other side I connect to this server using an x2go client installed in a windows 10 (1903) computer at home. I live in south america so I use a pc105 "latam" keyboard according to ubuntu. The thing is I can't get the keyboard settings right in x2go, nor does x2go "detect automatically" my keyboard. In the I/O settings of the client's x2go I filled the keyboard parameters with the following:

```
model: pc105
layout: latam
variant: (empty)
```

However, when I connect it to the server I can't type e.g. a dash "-" (it actually shows a backslash\ ) when I press the key next to the period. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks I'll edit the question. When I ssh to this server the first messsage says Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-29-generic x86_64)

Comment: FYI:  Your system is behind on updates; an upgraded 16.04 system will report as 16.04.7, so you're a year+ behind on upgrades & security fixes; http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/)